# How to Remove Padding from Blogger Posts and Pages

Tags: post, padding, blogger

Anyone know, how can I remove Left-Right-Bottom-Up padding from the Blogger Post.
See the IMAGE:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look for the piece of code below and play with the values I commented until you're happy with it.

```
#page_body .FeaturedPost, .Blog .blog-posts .post-outer-container {
    background: #ffffff;
    min-height: 40px;
    padding: 30px 40px; /*Play with this numbers */
    width: auto;
}
```

also about padding values:

```
padding: top right bottom left;
```

with just 2 values as it is present in your code:

```
padding: top/bottom right/left;
```